# Routing outlet not routing into same outlet

Tags: angular

So I have an app with two router outlets, one primary, and one named. A simple duplicate of the app has been constructed here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yyifnx?file=src/app/app.component.html

If you use the app you will notice the routing to the primary window on the left works - the main pages load. Similarly the routing to the second menu works... but when the 'main menu' button on the second menu is clicked, it doesn't route back to the main menu.

The behavior I need is for the primary outlet to stay the same (either on the main page or the 'wicked' route) when that button is clicked, but the right hand router outlet (right) goes back to the main menu.

The behavior I have is that when clicking to go back to the main menu, that route is said to not exist.

I think this is an issue in the routes constant in the app module but im not sure how to modify it to make it work correctly.

Bogo

Comment: can't find any routing module

Comment: its in the app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it work and indeed when you try to go back to main menu from that menu2 the console show an error indicating:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'menu2/%5B%7B%20outlets:%20%7B%20right:%20%5B'menu'%5D%20%7D%20%7D%5D'
```

The interesting thing here is that your path already include 'menu2/' as show in the error.

I have never used outlet indicated in your Routes in app.module.ts so I don't know how it works exactly but I got the expected result by changing the routerLink in menu2.component.ts from

```
<div [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { right: ['menu'] } }]">MAIN MENU</div>
```

to

```
<div routerLink="">MAIN MENU</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Nev, the only issue is that if you go to the second menu and use routerLink="" it will reset the primary outlet to its original state. So when you go back to the main menu, it will send the primary outlet back to its initial location too...